# SQL syntax error in custom module edit option

Tags: magento-1.7, database, custom

I have created a custom module for seller management in magento 1.7.0.2.
When I try to edit and save an entry in that module, I get a SQL syntax error.

---

### This is the error I get

[image]

---

This is the code of my Form.php

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl(
            'managesellers/index/save',
            array(
                '_current' => true,
                'continue' => 0,
            )
        ),
        'method' => 'post',
    ));


    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);


    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'general',
        array(
            'legend' => $this->__('Seller Details')
        )
    );
     $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
        'managesellers_id' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('ID'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
        ),

    ));
    $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
        'name' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Name'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

    ));
     $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
        'address' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Address'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

    ));
     $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
        'shipping_charges' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Shipping Charges'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

    ));
    $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
        'min_value' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Minimum Value'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

    ));

    //To fill the edit form with data
    $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
    $model= Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers')->load($id);
    $form->setValues($model->getData());

    return $this;
}

protected function _addFieldsToFieldset(
    Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset $fieldset, $fields)
{
    $requestData = new Varien_Object($this->getRequest()
        ->getPost('managesellersData'));

    foreach ($fields as $name => $_data) {
        if ($requestValue = $requestData->getData($name)) {
            $_data['value'] = $requestValue;
        }
        $_data['name'] = "managesellersData[$name]";
        $fieldset->addField($name, $_data['input'], $_data);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

---

This is my Controller.php

```
public function saveAction() 
{
    if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id') > 0 ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
            $model = Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers');
            $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id'))->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('managesellers_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

How can I solve this error.
Also, if there is any SQL queries to be written, where should I write those ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Update 1: Code Added

Update 2: Problem Solved

The problem was with the form which I created. I changed the code of my **form.php** & **saveAction()** method in **controller.php** and got it solved.

### Form.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_id = 'edit_form';
    $this->_title = $this->__('Seller Information');
}
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl(
            'managesellers/index/save',
            array(
                '_current' => true,
                'continue' => 0,
            )
        ),
        'method' => 'post',
    ));


    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('edit_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('Seller information')));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('name'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'name',
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('managesellers_id', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('managesellers_id'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'managesellers_id',
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('address', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('address'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'address',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('shipping_charges', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('shipping_charges'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'shipping_charges',
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('min_value', 'text', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('min_value'),
        'class'     => 'required-entry',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'min_value',
     ));

    if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getmanagesellersData() )
    {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getmanagesellersData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setmanagesellersData(null);
    }
    else if ( Mage::registry('managesellers_data')) 
    {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('managesellers_data')->getData());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

### saveAction() method

```
public function saveAction() 
{
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id') > 0 ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $model = Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers')->load($id);
            if ($model->isObjectNew() == false) 
            {
                $model->setData($postData);
                $model->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            } 
            else 
            {
                $model->setData($postData);
                $model->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {   
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('managesellers_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: Please share your code which you did so far.

Comment: Code Added @JaiminSutariya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save button saves empty row in edit form](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/save-button-saves-empty-row-in-edit-form)

Comment: `managesellers_id`  is primary key???

Comment: yes.. it is the primary key @GopalPatel

Answer (score 1):

Update your code from

```
$model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id'))->save();
```

To

```
$model->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost())->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id'))->save();
```

Comment: it didn't work  :(

Comment: Solved the problem. Added the answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks related to your other question (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/save-button-saves-empty-row-in-edit-form/158160#158160) for which I posted:

There looks to be 3 reasons for whats happening:

1. The form may not be populating the managesellers_id field correctly.
2. The code only uses managesellers_id from the post data, no other post data.
3. The row being updated is not being loaded. Doing $model->setId($id) will only set the data for the id, Magento will
   still think it's a "new" row and try to insert it, which may result
   in undesired behavior.

For "1": Without seeing the format of the DB table, it's hard to know this one. But based on the other code, it's treating managesellers_id like an ID for which it loads the data:

```
$id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
$model = Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers')->load($id);
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

But the form field is:

```
$this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
    'managesellers_id' => array(
        'label' => $this->__('ID'),
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
    ),
));
```

Unless the $model->getData() contains an entry for 'managesellers_id', then the form will not auto-populate the 'managesellers_id' field with data.

You could do this:

```
$id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
$model = Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers')->load($id);
$model->setManagesellersId($id);
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

This will mean the form gets the correct data in the field.

I'd also recommend that this field is not editable (you may have already planned on that though :) ). If someone comes along and changes that, the code could end up updating another row in the database, wiping out another row's information.

It should either have a field type of hidden, or if you do need to display it set to readonly: 'readonly' => true,

For 2 & 3:

The saveAction should be tweaked so that it:

- Uses the postdata
- Loads the model so that Magento knows which row to update.

Something a bit more like this:

```
public function saveAction() 
{
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id') > 0 ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $model = Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers')->load($id);
            if ($model->isObjectNew() == false) {
                $model->setData($postData);
                $model->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved %s',$id));
            } else {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Could not find ID %s, no data updated',$id));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('managesellers_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: Didn't work.. getting an error..
It is adding a new row with new id and blank data.
P.S-  **managesellers_id** is an auto-increment field.

Comment: Solved the problem and updated the answer. 
Thanks for your help :)